# I want to set some columns' border as thick, but all columns are be set

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to set the rigth border of all cells of column 2 and the last column in excel sheet as thick, the others are thin. But the effect is all columns' borders are thick.

Here's my code

```
for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);

        style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        if(j == 1 || j == row.getLastCellNum()-1){
            style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
        }

        style.setTopBorderColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);
        style.setBottomBorderColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);
        style.setLeftBorderColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);
        style.setRightBorderColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);   
        System.out.println("Row:"+i+", Column:"+j+", BorderRightStyleIndex:"+style.getBorderRight());

        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
}
```

And here's the infomation in console

```
Row:355, Column:0, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:1, BorderRightStyleIndex:5
Row:355, Column:2, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:3, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:4, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:5, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:6, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:7, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:8, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:9, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:355, Column:10, BorderRightStyleIndex:5
Row:356, Column:0, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:1, BorderRightStyleIndex:5
Row:356, Column:2, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:3, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:4, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:5, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:6, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:7, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:8, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:9, BorderRightStyleIndex:1
Row:356, Column:10, BorderRightStyleIndex:5
```

Which part of my code goes wrong? Why all columns' border are thick?

Comment: All cells get the same `style` applied. So the last settings of that `style` are the ones which are used. That are the ones with thick right border. You need at least **two** `CellStyle`s, one without and one with thick right border. Then apply one of the both cell styles as needed. Another approach would be using `PropertyTemplate` as shown in [DrawingBorders](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DrawingBorders).

Comment: Thank you, Axel Richter, this's the point! All cells get the same style, if I change something of this style, looks like just this cell will change, but the fact is it will change all cells which are set this style. When I create a new style of some special cells, the problem is solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`Excel`'s cell styles are stored on workbook level. Thats why `apache poi`'s `CellStyles` also are on `Workbook` level. So in your code there is one and only `CellStyle` `style`. According to your code, all cells get this same `style` applied. So the last settings of that `style` are the ones which are used. That are the ones with thick right border.

You need at least two `CellStyles`, one without and one with thick right border. Then apply one of the both cell styles to your `Cell`s as needed.

Another approach would be using `PropertyTemplate` as shown in [DrawingBorders](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DrawingBorders). Since this is best practice, in my opinion, I will show how to do this. The following code first draws thin border lines around all cells in table area. Then it additional draws a thick right border line in second and last column of the table area.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.PropertyTemplate;

class DrawingBorders {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Excel.xls"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  boolean emptySheet = false;

  int headerRowNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
  Row headerRow = sheet.getRow(headerRowNum);

  if (headerRow == null) emptySheet = true;

  if (!emptySheet) {
   int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
   short firstCol = headerRow.getFirstCellNum();
   short lastCol = headerRow.getLastCellNum();
   lastCol--;

   PropertyTemplate pt = new PropertyTemplate();
   pt.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(
    headerRowNum,
    lastRow,
    firstCol,
    lastCol), BorderStyle.THIN, BorderExtent.ALL);

   if (lastCol - firstCol > 1) {
    pt.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(
     headerRowNum,
     lastRow,
     firstCol + 1,
     firstCol + 1), BorderStyle.THICK, BorderExtent.RIGHT);
   }

   pt.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(
    headerRowNum,
    lastRow,
    lastCol,
    lastCol), BorderStyle.THICK, BorderExtent.RIGHT);

   pt.applyBorders(sheet);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ExcelWithBorders.xls");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```